# Can I match multiline string in python without using re.DOTALL?

Tags: python, regex

I'm attempting to write a simple lexer in python.
I'm using regular expressions to do it.
So, I need a regular expression matching a multiline comment:

```
/* first line.
the second line
The last line. */
```

By using this pattern:

```
pattern = r"/\*.*\*/"
```

and compiling it with

```
regex = re.compile(pattern,re.DOTALL)
```

it works.

Now, i won't use `re.DOTALL`, 'cause this works also with single-quoted strings.
Is there a way to compile this expression in order to work without `re.DOTALL?`

Comment: Use a character class containing the dot and a newline character.

Comment: You need to escape the asterisks.

Comment: You probably want `r'/\*.*?\*/'`; note the `.*?` instead of `.*`.  This will make the regular expression give you the shortest match possible instead of the longest match possible.  Try it on inputs like `/* a */ b /* c */`... my guess is that you want two matches, instead of just one.

Comment: Could you elaborate what is the problem with _dotall_ and single-quoted strings ? If you are trying to parse c-style comments, this isn't the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the same by using a little trick like this `[\s\S]`.

The idea behind `[\s\S]` is to capture everything, so you can delimit what you want using an explicit pattern. For instance:

```
/\*        <--- Match /*
[\s\S]*?   <--- Match everything (ungreedy)
\*/        <--- Match */
```

You can use a regex like this:

```
/\*[\s\S]*?\*/
```

If you want to capture the content within the comment then you could do:

```
/\*([\s\S]*?)\*/
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/mW2eQ5/1)**

You can see how this trick works below:

[image]

Btw, you are using a greedy regex `/\*.*\*/` that will wrongly match comments. For instance, if you have:

```
/* A */
/* B */
```

You regex will wrongly match `/* A *//* B */`. You have to add `?` to set it as ungreedy as this:

```
/\*.*?\*/
     ^--- ungreedy
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to `re.XXX` constants you can use inline flags:

```
re.match('(?s)/\*.*?\*/', stuff)
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> (?iLmsux)
>   (One or more letters from the set 'i', 'L', 'm', 's', 'u', 'x'.) The group matches the empty string; the letters set the corresponding flags: re.I (ignore case), re.L (locale dependent), re.M (multi-line), re.S (dot matches all), re.U (Unicode dependent), and re.X (verbose), for the entire regular expression.

I prefer inlines to `re.XXX` flags for two reasons: 1) expressions are self-contained and 2) no need to use `compile` or to append the `flags` param to every `re.` call.

Comment: You don't have to use `compile` either way, you can pass flags to e.g. `re.match()`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: thanks, I forgot about that. Never used flags this way.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to enumerate all possibilies, I'll also post my answer:

`/\*(?:[\r\n]|[^\r\n])*\*/`

See [example here](https://regex101.com/r/tF2wY5/1).

However, it requires 147 steps to compute with your example, while Fede's `/\*[\s\S]*\*/` only needs 12.

If we compare performance between the versions with capturing groups - `/\*((?:[\r\n]|[^\r\n])*)\*/` and `/\*([\s\S]*?)\*/`, the ratio is already not that large: 151 vs. 97 steps.

Comment: Using alternation here is not a good idea. Most regex engines don't really optimize the character class here, so it will create a choice point after every character matched, compared to the `(?s).` or `[\s\S]` method which don't create any choice point.